# Is there a simple way of defaulting out of bounds in nested Seqs in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've got a Vector of Vectors that I'm accessing to apply a boolean function. i.e.

`Vector[Vector[T]]` where I'm going to execute something along the lines of
`f(myVector(i)(j))` where f is of type `T => Boolean`.

But this does not do bounds checking, and I can't get something really elegant.

I can use `applyOrElse`:
`myVector.applyOrElse(i, (_:Int) => Vector.empty).applyOrElse (j, (_:Int) => defaultT)`

where `f(defaultT)` would return `false`
But I wish I could just set a default Value instead of a function.

I could use lift to give me an `Option`, but it doesn't compose well at the second level:
`myVector.lift(i) map (_.lift(j) map f getOrElse false) getOrElse false`

Which does work, but is still really hard to read.

And then there's standard if/else blocks:

```
if (myVector.size <= i) false
else {
  val myVector2 = levelVector(i)
  if (myVector2.size <= j) false
  else f(myVector2(j))
}
```

It just seems like something that should be able to be decomposed easier than what I can achieve. And if I add a 3rd layer, it's gets even uglier.

Are there other options?

*Disclaimer: this is adapted from coursera's progfun course*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the following code from the question:

```
myVector.lift(i) map (_.lift(j) map f getOrElse false) getOrElse false
```

This can be rewritten as follows:

```
myVector.lift(i).flatMap(_.lift(j)).fold(false)(f)
```

Or, before `fold` was introduced in Scala 2.10:

```
myVector.lift(i).flatMap(_.lift(j)).map(f).getOrElse(false)
```

The key idea is to defer unwrapping (or mapping) the `Option` for as long as possible. This approach will generalize quite naturally to more than two dimensions.

This is pretty close to equivalent to the `for`-comprehension in your answer (assuming you meant to include `lift` in there), but once you have to wrap the comprehension in parentheses I personally tend to find the desugared version clearer.

Comment: Fantastic - I was trying to hold the Option but forgot about the fundamentals of the list comprehension. Thanks.

Comment: 2.10 shorter version:
`myVector.lift(i).flatMap(_.lift(j)).exists(f)`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured something that seems elegant, even if it seems to be a bit overkill:

```
(for {
   myVector2 <- myVector(i)
   t <- myVector2(j)
} yield t) map f getOrElse false
```

Is this sensible? It's certainly readable. Is it slow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you vector is named `vec` and your predicate is named `pred`, this expression will yield right value: `vec.lift(p.row).fold(false)(_.lift(p.col).fold(false)(pred(_))`